# How can you format JavaScript / html stings in set width?

Tags: javascript, codepen

I want to create a multiply 10 x 10 board.
Each "cell" shall have the same width.

```js
for (i = 1; i < 11; i++) {
  for (j = 1; j < 11; j++) {
    document.write(i * j + " ")
  }
  document.write("<br>")
}
```

Comment: Just pad with zeros or spaces.

Comment: What @D.Pardal said + use a monospace font

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/padStart

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This solution works with `pre` and the html tab entity `&#9;`

```js
document.write("<pre>")
  for (let i = 1; i < 11; i++) {
    for (let j = 1; j < 11; j++)
      document.write(i * j + "&#9;")
    document.write("<br>")
  }
document.write("</pre>")
```

You can control the space with css `tab-size`:

```
* {
    -moz-tab-size: 3em;
    -o-tab-size: 3em;
    tab-size: 3em;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Solution using [`String.prototype.padStart()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/padStart):

```js
let html = "";
for (let i = 1; i < 11; i++) {
  for (let j = 1; j < 11; j++) {
    html += String(i * j).padStart(3, " ") + " ";
  }
  html += "<br>";
}
document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = html.replace(/ /g, "&nbsp;");
```

```css
#output {
  font-family: monospace;
}
```

```html
<output id="output"></output>
```

Comment: `padStart` is not supported by IE.

Answer (score 2):

use

- <pre> The Preformatted Text element
- native [String.prototype.padStart()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/padStart)

```js
document.write("<pre>")
for (i = 1; i < 11; i++) {
  for (j = 1; j < 11; j++) {
    document.write(String(i * j).padStart(4, ' '))
  }
  document.write("<br>")
}
document.write("</pre>")
```

Comment: `padStart` is not supported by IE.

Comment: on the end of docs link is See also [A polyfill](https://github.com/behnammodi/polyfill/blob/53ded2aa0c0ba803421485849dcb676c6b90d284/string.polyfill.js#L273-L294) - it's job of build process support IE polyfills in my POV

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of issues in your code:

- you should use a [`<pre>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/pre) (pre-formatted text) tag
- you should add a `let` in front of the `i` and `j` index to reduce their scope locally to the `for`
- in the `for` loops, you would improve readability if you define the index conditions as `<= 10` (since you're counting numbers from 1 to 10) instead of `< 11`
- you need a prefix and a suffix (to build the prefix in my example I used a function)

```js
document.write('<pre>');
for (let i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
  for (let j = 1; j <= 10; j++) {
    let number = i * j;
    let prefix = get_prefix(number);
    let suffix = '&nbsp;';
    document.write(prefix + number + suffix)
  }
  document.write('<br>')
}
document.write('</pre>');

function get_prefix(number) {
  let prefix = '';
  if (number < 100) {
    prefix += '&nbsp;';
  }
  if (number < 10) {
    prefix += '&nbsp;';
  }
  return prefix;
}
```